# Matrix calculus over a non-commutative ring

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for references on **Matrices over a non-commutative ring $\rm R$**, particularly on conditions on $\rm R$ to provide diagonalisation or trigonalisation theorems.

> Any reference for that ?

Comment: Do you just want to learn noncommutative algebra in general? Farb and Dennis is a good read. (Though, I'm not sure it is what you desire.)

Comment: @Alex Clark. Thanks for your answer, I remember learning interesting things about the Brauer group in Farb and Dennis, but, I am more looking today for down-to-earth matrices calculations, which does not appear in F&D I think.

Comment: I've heard of work on the eigenvalue problem over the quaternions, but not over general non-commutative rings.